# Xcode Simulator does not show additionally installed iOS versions

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I had crash reports for iOS 11.4.1 on iPhone 8 Plus, so I installed iOS 11.4 by 'Download Simulators' below the iOS Simulator list. It downloaded and shows a green checkmark as installed.

Although my application supports iOS 10.0 (and I can see iOS 10.3.1 for some simulators) iOS 11.4 does not show up for any of the devices. I restarted the application as well.

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: which Xcode version you are using?

Comment: 10.2.1, latest release

Answer (score 1):

You can add already installed simulator to the list from following option:

Open Similator list (Right side of project name) -> Add additional simulators:

[image]

Tap on + add button to add installed simulators to the list

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I can not devices with 11.4 in that list. Basically, it's only 10.3.1 and 12.2. I've tried to install other versions now, but they are also not available.

Comment: @nontomatic Basically its depends upon the Device Type that you have selected while adding / creating new simulator. e.g. iPhone 5 device will not show iOS 11 and greater but iPhone 6 will show.

Comment: I checked again, I did have the proper device type selected. I'm aware of that issue.

Comment: As stated above, I'm using 10.2.1

Comment: Yes I have already read that. I am just asking that can you check with Xcode 10.2 to make sure that is this issue related to Xcode version or something related to simulator configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Go for New Scheme option and add a new scheme. You'll find the newly downloaded simulators. Seems like Xcode bug. I just tried the same which worked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did just that and the additionally downloaded simulators are still not visible. Do I need to refresh that list somehow?

Comment: Is the deployment target <= 11.4 ? Double check that

Comment: Yes, as stated above, the deployment target is 10.0